# mingw-64 GCC is broken under Ubuntu

Tags: gcc, cmake, cross-compilation

I'm trying to cross-compile SFML from Linux to Windows for a project of mine. Prebuilt SFML packages are not an option.

So, I installed the mingw-w64 package,and set up a toolchain file, and went ahead trying to compile SFML from source using CMake, only to find that the GCC compiler provided is broken.

Full error message:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:61 (message):
  The C compiler "/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc" is not able to compile a
  simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

   Change Dir: /home/chemicalchems/SFML-2.3.2/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp



  Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_9b6e7/fast"

  /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_9b6e7.dir/build.make
  CMakeFiles/cmTC_9b6e7.dir/build

  make[1]: Entering directory
  '/home/chemicalchems/SFML-2.3.2/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

  Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_9b6e7.dir/testCCompiler.c.o

  /usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -o
  CMakeFiles/cmTC_9b6e7.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c
  /home/chemicalchems/SFML-2.3.2/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c

  Linking C executable cmTC_9b6e7

  /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_9b6e7.dir/link.txt
  --verbose=1

  /usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc CMakeFiles/cmTC_9b6e7.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
  -o cmTC_9b6e7 -rdynamic

  i686-w64-mingw32-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option
  ‘-rdynamic’

  CMakeFiles/cmTC_9b6e7.dir/build.make:97: recipe for target 'cmTC_9b6e7'
  failed

  make[1]: *** [cmTC_9b6e7] Error 1

  make[1]: Leaving directory
  '/home/chemicalchems/SFML-2.3.2/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

  Makefile:126: recipe for target 'cmTC_9b6e7/fast' failed

  make: *** [cmTC_9b6e7/fast] Error 2
```

So the problem is that i686-w64-mingw32-gcc doesn't accept the `-rdynamic` option. I've tried telling CMake that it should not test the C compiler in my toolchain file but it keeps on checking it and thus failing.

Toolchain file:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR i686)
set(CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING 1)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS 1)

set(TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX i686-w64-mingw32)

# cross compilers to use for C and C++
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}-g++)
set(CMAKE_RC_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}-windres)

# target environment on the build host system
#   set 1st to dir with the cross compiler's C/C++ headers/libs
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH /usr/${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX})

# modify default behavior of FIND_XXX() commands to
# search for headers/libs in the target environment and
# search for programs in the build host environment
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact problem in Ubuntu 20.04
Funny enough, as well wanting to compile SFML.

You were almost there actually with the `CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS`. However the correct options is `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_WORKS`